# How do I disable font anti-aliasing in Firefox, while keeping font hinting on?

Tags: firefox, fonts

AA makes everything blurry, and without hinting, some poorly designed fonts(which are widespread) make my eyes bleed. Is there no way to get the best of o

Comment: what's your operating system?

Comment: Windows 7, 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `about:config`
Find the preference `gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.rendering_mode`
Change its value (probably -1) to 1

1 turns anti-aliasing off.
You might also want to try 2 and 3.

4 and 5 are not your friends, they involve anti-aliasing.

Comment: That turns off both anti-aliasing, and font-hinting. I would like font-hinting to stay enabled.

Comment: I didn't see this option under Firefox 36.0.1

Comment: @TrevorHickey it's a Windows-only preference. Is that your OS?

Comment: @paa Ubuntu.  I was able to successfully turned off antaliasing with a .fonts.config file.

Comment: Do you know how to turn off antialiasing in Firefox for Mac?